# How to update parent with children, without changing children primary keys?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a following one-to-many structure:

```
public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        this.Schools = new List<School>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<School> Schools { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

My problem: when I'm updating `City` that includes a `School` collection, everything works great, but primary keys for each school changes. It's like EF first update changes in the `City` entity, then deletes all schools and then adds cities from request.

I understand that EF can't recognize which schools changed, which were added or removed, so that's why I does what it does, but here is my question:

How can I prevent EF from touching the `School` collection at all? Just change the `City` and I can handle changes in schools manually. I was trying this, but it still changes city along with all schools:

```
    public override void Update(City city)
    {
        var existingCity = _context.Cities
                                   .Include(p => p.Schools)
                                   .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CityId == city.CityId);

        if (existingCity != null)
        {
            _context.Entry(existingCity).CurrentValues.SetValues(city);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

To clarify, this is what I'm looking for:

1. When parent with children is being deleted - I want to keep CascadeDelete and delete children
2. When parent with children is being inserted - I want to insert parent and children
3. When parent with children is being updated - I want to update only parent. I don't want to touch children.

#1 and #2 works for me. I have a problem with #3.

Comment: How about to do not use `SetValues` and update only needed fields of `existingCity` explicitly?

Comment: The code as you show it should only change scalar properties of `existingCity`. That's what `SetValues` does. So I don't understand how the problem can occur. Either way, just don't `Include` the schools if you don't need them, why would you get that much data for only modifying a city?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` you could specify how EF will handle child entities once the parent entity has been deleted;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-6.0

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Schools)
      .WithOne(c => c.City)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction);
}
```

In your school class, you might need to add a navigation property to City;

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public City City { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Also in your code, it looks like you are replacing the entire entity including its navigation properties. I suggest you update individual properties;

```
public override void Update(City city)
{
   var existingCity = _context.Cities
      .Include(p => p.Schools)
      .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CityId == city.CityId);

   if (existingCity != null)
   {  
      // you could update individual properties only
      existingCity.CityId = city.CityId;

      _context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep onCascade delete. All I want is when updating parent that has children, to NOT delete/recreate these children. So, when parent is being inserted - I want to insert children, when parent is being deleted I want to delete children, BUT.. when parent is being updated I don't want to touch children

Comment: @AdamWojnar have you tried the last code above which updates only specific properties?

Comment: Oh, I didn't try that. That could work! Thanks, I will try that shorty